# Driver for AMD® Ryzen 7 5800h with radeon graphics Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics

I have a laptop ASUS TUF GAMING A15 with AMD® Ryzen 7 5800h processor, integrate graphic processor AMD Radeon™ Graphics and video chipset nVidia GeForce RTX model RTX 3070. I am using Ubuntu 20.10 and kernel Version 5.11.12. (as newer kernels supposedly provide better support for Ryzen 7, although I've tried 5.8.15 and increased through to this one without seeing any change).

The screen brightness is not adjustable, the HDMI and USB-C ports doesn't work. I can't connect to external displays and after trying to install NVIDIA driver I have a black screen and I need to uninstall driver in order to use desktop UI again.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You need to disable Secure Boot.

Comment: 20.10 shipped with kernel 5.4 did you try that? To see if the other issues go away.

Comment: Just tried kernel 5.4 and still does not work.:(

Comment: @David do you think that those issues are from Ubuntu version? Do you think that if I will downgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS will be different?

Comment: As far as I know the difference between 20.10 and 20.04 is that 20.04 is LTS 5 year and 20.10 is 3 year but basically the same. So no I do not think that will help. Keep in mind on the 30 th comes 21.04

Comment: Have you check for firmware updates from the vendor -- those can help many problems?  Non-LTS release support is only 9 months.  Ubuntu 21.04 was released today, the 22nd.

Comment: Got familiar problem, lenovo IdeaPad 5 Pro with R7 5800H and integrated GPU. Had general problem with wifi-adapter, found custom driver on github, but it's stable only for kernel <= 5.4. When installed Ubuntu 20.04.01 (with kernel = 5.4), problem with brightness functional keys arises. Now I'm searching for gpu drivers (on manufacturer site there only drivers for win10 win11)